# JMeter BeanShell Assertion using "size in bytes" data

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I have such BeanShell Assertion code:

```
final String response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
final String expectedExceptionText = "numberOfFeatures=\"0\"";

if (response.contains(expectedExceptionText)) {
   Failure = true;
   FailureMessage = "At least one feature expected ";
}
```

and I'd like to check if 'size in bytes' response is bigger than 384B. If not then i need to count all responses below 384 in some variable. Is there a way to use the response 'size in bytes' in my assertion code ? i mean i don't know how to do it so please advise me.

//edit

I ve been trying to use method getBytes but it does not work despite i have required imports. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need BeanshellAssertion to do this:

- To check size use [Size Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion)
- To check content use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), pay attention to the **Not** checkbox

If you still want to use Beanshell, then:

> if (SampleResult.getResponseData().length>384)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to check only. I m using Size and Response Assertions already to check if i get proper response but i'd like to count responses which are empty( i m doing getImage requests) and it may return 200 response but it could still be empty. I would like to know while that happens and at the same time encounter variable. Below example what i'd like to have:

```
1st request - image ok 200.  variable =0;
2nd image ok 200. variable = 0
3rd no image, 200, variable =1;
etc.
```

I need that to check how much of delivered data(input arguments) is empty. 
I checked that response without image has 384 bytes so i wanted to check it in that way. I tried to use getBytes() method but it does not work in BeanShell. I`m receiving some errors.
//edit

I used your method and it seems that works. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Beanshell Assertion you can get response size in bytes in at least 2 ways:

```
ResponseData.length
SampleResult.getResponseData().length
```

Both result in byte array - `byte[]` containing parent sampler response.

so something like:

```
if (ResponseData.length > 384) {
    //do what you need
}
```

should resolve your use case.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for advanced information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter